# Ds18b20 not detected

Tags: raspbian, gpio

I'm having an issue with my ds18b20.

Raspberry pi 2 model b v1.1
Raspbian Jessie 4.1.13-v7+

I've added w1-gpio and also w1-therm to /etc/modules as well as dtoverlay=w1-gpio to /boot/config.txt

I've done `sudo apt-update` and `sudo apt-upgrade`.

My sensor is hooked up to pin 1 to power, pin 7 (gpio 4) to data and pin 6 to ground with a 4.7k resistor between pin 1 and pin 7 (gpio 4)

Also have a second ds18b20 that I bought from a local store that is from df robot (with a 4.7k resistor built into the board.), same issue.

When I cd to /sys/bus/w1/devices/ and see what's in there, I only get the master bus 1 and no sensor (either version that I own)

Am I missing something here?

Edit: pictures of the setup

[image: board]
[image: bread board]
[image: adding another picture]
after sudo modprobe w1-therm
[image: after sudo modprobe w1-therm]

Comment: Just tried getting rid of w1-gpio and w1-therm from /etc/modules/.  No change.

Comment: The dtoverlay line in /boot/config.txt and no w1-* entries in /etc/modules is correct.  Does lsmod show the modules as loaded after boot?  Could you post an image of your setup?

Comment: lsmod shows the modules w1_gpio, wire and cn all loaded.  I had posted a pic but it was quickly deleted

Comment: Sorry about that. The first post seems somewhat off. I edited your question to include the other pics though. If in need of the third picture we can have it unburried by a mod. Added: ok, I see that you posted the link yourself.

Comment: @MikeCarleton Your lsmod is missing w1-therm.  Have you got it blacklisted somewhere?  Can you modprobe it manually and does it then appear in lsmod?

Comment: Joan, I did the modprobe w1-therm.  I have not black listed anything as of yet.  This is a fresh install.  I had wheezy yesterday but updated to Jessie ( formatted my sd card and downloaded the newest noobs ). As soon as it's peer reviewed, I added a new picture

Comment: @joan, still not working

Comment: @steverobillard and @ ghanima... I saw you guys briefly discus in the bakery, the fact that I posted my question the wrong way but have also noticed the lack of helpful answers to said question... Maybe one of you gurus can point someone who knows how to help me in my direction...  Thanks

Comment: @MikeCarleton It should just work and w1-therm should have been in the list of modules.  Something is broken, and I'd have to assume it broke during the upgrade from wheezy to jessie.  As this is a fresh install I'd just download the latest Raspbian and start again from scratch.

Comment: Thank you @joan... I'll do a fresh install and report back

Comment: As no one else has said it: "Welcome to the Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange"! - I think I got one of these in the bits I got with one of my Pis (can I check the pin out is Red: 3.3V, Yellow: Serial Data, Black: Ground - not using the "parasite power" option?) - I remember that if there is only one device, the controller (the Pi) can taker some short-cuts so that it has to do more if there is more than one of these temperature sensors on the 1-wire bus.

Comment: @joan,  so I formatted my ad card and installed a fresh copy of Jessie from the terminal in mac OS X.  All I have done so far is add dtoverlay=w1-gpio to /boot/config.txt... Lsmod shows no w1-therm once again. I used sudo modprobe w1-therm and it shows up.  Still no sensor.  That is all that I have done so far.  What else can I try?  Can someone who knows one wire stuff please chime in?  Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately mine just work.  An alernative may be to look for posts by danjperron on https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/ He has successfully bit banged the DS18B20 and can do things not possible with the standard kernel driver.

Comment: @joan,  I see the many post by Dan but am not sure what I need to be doing with his github repository.  I'm a new Linux user and am still trying to get the hang of it.  I've look for a "how to" with his bitbanging but can not seem to find one.  I appreciate the help you have given me so far.  Btw... Can you think of a reason that w1-therm is not showing up after the dtoverlay step?  I am very stumped and really do thank you for your input

Comment: @MikeCarleton I don't know why your system does not work.  At least one other person also had a seemingly intractable problem.  I'd get a fresh SD card, install the latest Raspbian image (not via NOOBS), and try that.  If that doesn't work I'd use a different sensor. Dan is very approachable.

Comment: Just in case anyone else reads this... I bought a new ad card and reinstalled Jessie (not noobs) using dd on Mac OS X and still am not able to use any ds18b20's. It sure would be great if someone on here would be able to tell me a few things.  1.) any idea why w1_therm is not loading when dtoverlay=w1-gpio is added to /boot/config.txt.  2.) is anyone else having the same issue? Have you fixed it?  3.) is there anything else I might be able to try?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good [App Note](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-11-ds18b20-temperature-sensing/ds18b20) on the adafruit website for configuring this temperature sensor. It lists a couple of steps that you haven't so it is a good place to start.

(I know it's an old question but hopefully it helps somebody)